# Laptop with new SSD, Partitioning and Over-Provision

Tags: partitioning, laptop, ssd

I upgraded my laptop with an Samsung 840 EVO 120GB SSD for programming purposes.
I'm going to install Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS on it.

This installation of Ubuntu will get four primary partitions, I'm not going to use any dual boot or something else, just Ubuntu.
These partitions will be together 91136 MB, there will be around 15 GB left as "unusable space" because of the four primary partition limit.
It will be partitioned on the following way:

Boot: 1024 MB Primary
Root: 40960 MB Primary
Home: 40960 MB Primary
Swap: 8192 MB Primary
And some "unusable space" (15 GB)

My question is, will this "unusable space" be automatically available for OP (Over-Provision) on the SSD? Or do I need to have three partitions and some "unallocated space" to get the OP working?

Thank you in advance!

Greetings,
Nils

Comment: If only installing Ubuntu and system is BIOS or UEFI, you can use gpt partitioning and then you do not have a partition limit. With BIOS you have to add a small 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag. If UEFI you have to have an efi partition. I have used gpt since 10.10 on my old BIOS system without issue. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901

Comment: My laptop doesn't support UEFI. I should stick with the old MBR and go for four primary partitions. I'm fine with that, only uncertain about the unusable space (if OP will recognize it).

Comment: If I may suggest, you might want to use a swap file instead of swap partition, especially if you have sufficient memory

Answer (score 1):

Over provisioning simply means never writing to some part of the drive.  It doesn't matter if part of the drive is in a partition you never use, or not assigned to any partition at all -- either way, you never write there.

On the other hand, occasionally running `fstrim` is better than over provisioning the drive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So it doesn't matter if I make four primary partitions (the max of MBR), and leave the 15GB as "unusable space"? Is it not true that since Ubuntu 14.04 the trim works automatically if I'm right?

Comment: @NilsBerlijn, you have to edit /etc/fstab to request the trim mount option to enable it to be done automatically, or you can run `fstrim` every once in a while.  The latter seems to be the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're OK, the 15G will be used as needed.  The new disks recommend 10% (12G) but the older ones recommended 20% , so you are in the middle.  The partitioning should not make any difference.

Comment: Thank you, interesting answer. The conclusion is that I can make **FOUR** (max) primary partitions, and leave some space left as "unusable space" that cannot be partitioned anymore without any problems for the OP?

Comment: Correct. Four is max primary for MSDOS partitioning. You could still make one extended, and add more logicals if you want more than four.

Comment: I don't need more than four as I sayd before. I like it to have four primary partitions for my Ubuntu installation and remain some GB's for the OP. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use fstrim with full-disk encryption (i.e.: LUKS) then your entire hard drive will be filled from the start (with noise) and fstrim won't help at all.

Over-provisioning should not be discounted when doing full-disk encryption.  I try to leave a partition of "free space" that is outside the encryption container, but I am having problems with that with the Ubuntu 14.04.3 installer.

Comment: If I encrypt one of my partitions then the whole drive will not be filled with noise, which is what people usually do: encrypting partitions not whole drives, but they call it FDE. Contrary TRIM actually works well with encrypted disks which is a [security issue](http://asalor.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/trim-dm-crypt-problems.html) if you felt comfortable with a whole drive of noise that only the FDE driver with the credentials knows how to read.